# HTTP: Is it necessary to close a connection with finish after opening a connection with new?

Tags: ruby, http

There are several methods in the Net::HTTP API shipped with Ruby core. Some like Net::HTTP.get, Net::HTTP.get_response and Net::HTTP.post_form do not persist connections. However, ::start and ::new do persist connections. In fact, ::start takes a block remains with open connection until block exits:

```
uri = URI("example.com")
Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) do |http|
  response1 = http.get('path1')
  response2 = http.get('path2')
end
```

Now you can use ::new instead of ::start:

```
  http = Net::HTTP.new('example.com')
  http.start
  response1 = http.get('path1')
  response2 = http.get('path2')
```

But must I manually close the connection? Is this a necessity or can I get away with not using this:

```
begin
  http = Net::HTTP.new('example.com')
  http.start
  response1 = http.get('path1')
  response2 = http.get('path2')
ensure
  http.finish
end
```

If I skip the finish call, will this create some kind of bloat or memory leak in the application?

Comment: The block form of `http.start` calls `ensure; do_finish`, and `finish` calls `do_finish`. There doesn't seem to be a destructor to call `finish` for you, though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `new` does not open the connection, according to the documentation:

> Creates a new Net::HTTP object without opening a TCP connection or
>   HTTP session.

But to answer your question, yes, you should close your connections after using them. The connection will close eventually, but it is simply bad practice not to clean up your own unmanaged resources when you are done with them.

The preferred method is the way you demonstrated, using `start` with a block, which ensures the connection will close when the block exits.

**EDIT**

I was not specific enough. I was referring to the class method `start`, not the instance method `start`. The class method signature looks like this:

```
start(address, port, p_addr, p_port, p_user, p_pass, &block)
start(address, port=nil, p_addr=nil, p_port=nil, p_user=nil, p_pass=nil, opt, &block)
```

Documentation for it can be found [here](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-c-start), though I am sure you can figure out the parameters already.

Comment: But if ::start is the preferred method, then how can you pass HTTP parameters to ::start? Like use_ssl, verify_mode, etc.

Comment: I updated my answer, wasn't specific enough. There is a class method `start`, not the instance method version. The class method takes a block and parameters.